# How can I mark two columns in the middle of text

Tags: grep

How can I mark two columns in the middle of text.

```
grep --color '^[[:alnum:]]*[[:blank:]]' file
```

This mark text in the beginning, but I want to mark second and third columns. How can pass first one?

Comment: Suggestion: use `gawk` to add terminal escape sequences to `$2` and `$3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this with GNU grep:

```
grep --color -P '^[[:alnum:]]+[[:blank:]]+\K[[:alnum:]]+[[:blank:]]+[[:alnum:]]+' file
```

Comment: What 'K' means? I can't find it in man.

Comment: Remove `\K` to see the difference. If `\K` appears in a Perl Regex (enabled by grep's option `-P`), it causes the regex matcher to drop everything before that point from the internal record.